# The annotate with Sum seems doesn't work Django

Tags: django

There's a db (`mysql`) table like below:

```
class AccountsInsightsHourly(models.Model):
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    spend = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hour = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'accounts_insights_hourly'
        unique_together = (('account_id', 'date', 'hour'),)
        ordering = ["account_id", "hour"]
```

Some datas saved in db are like :

```
id  account_id    spend    date        hour   created_time 

1     1222         200     20200820    12      ....
1     1222         300     20200820    14      ....
```

And I tried with to get the max spend for each account at the  specified date.

```
base_queryset_yesterday = AccountsInsightsHourly.objects.filter(date=date_yesterday). \
            annotate(yesterday_spend=Max("spend", output_field=FloatField())). \
            values("account_id", "yesterday_spend")

# I got results like below

<QuerySet [{'account_id': '1222', 'yesterday_spend': 200}, {'account_id': '1222', 'yesterday_s
pend': 300}]>




# expected result is 

<QuerySet [{'account_id': '1222', 'yesterday_spend': 300}>
```

How can I make annotate work as expected?

> Update

Thanks for [ruddra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696165/ruddra)'s help the correct queryset should be

```
base_queryset_yesterday = AccountsInsightsHourly.objects.filter(date=date_yesterday).values("account_id"). \
            annotate(yesterday_spend=Max("spend", output_field=FloatField())). \
            values("account_id", "yesterday_spend").\
            order_by()
```

[interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
base_queryset_yesterday = AccountsInsightsHourly.objects.filter(date=date_yesterday).values("account_id"). \
            annotate(yesterday_spend=Max("spend", output_field=FloatField())). \
            values("account_id", "yesterday_spend")
```

It will generate a `GROUP_BY` query like this:

```
'SELECT "accounts_insights_hourly"."account_id", MAX("accounts_insights_hourly"."spend") AS "yesterday_spend" FROM "accounts_insights_hourly" WHERE "accounts_insights_hourly"."date" = 2020-08-21 GROUP BY "accounts_insights_hourly"."account_id"'
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but It returned me `<QuerySet [{'yesterday_spend': 200}, {'yesterday_spend': 300}]>
`

Comment: Can you please see the updated answer? It should return query: `'SELECT "AccountsInsightsHourly"."account_id", MAX("AccountsInsightsHourly"."spend") AS "yesterday_spend" FROM "AccountsInsightsHourly" GROUP BY "AccountsInsightsHourly"."account_id"'`

Comment: Still same result got , and the `sql query` printed show the group by  is ` GROUP BY `accounts_insights_hourly`.`account_id`,
`accounts_insights_hourly`.`hour``  It's confused me .

Comment: thanks for your patience, and I add `order_by()` at end of the queryset, it finally worked.